# How to show map tips at once of layers that have the same coordinates

Tags: layers, coordinates, qgis2web, maptips

I want to show at once map tips of three layers that are located at the same coordinate in qgis2web for user to know when they pass over that point that there it is information of those three different layers. I am using Qgis3.24 and for now I've tried with the leaflet option and the opensource option and I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your intent correctly.  Do you want to query 3 different layers that each have 1 point in the same coordinate?  If so, update qgis2web to the latest version and export with openlayers by activating the "show popup on hover" option, then go to the ./layers/layers.js file and transform all declutter:true to declutter:false .